# Errors display when I run in my localhost

Tags: php, email

I have mail.php in my local server. And when I try to run I get this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'r' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Email\Mail.php on line 21
```

After I fix that error, there's a new errors display

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /htdocs/Email/CashPickup.xml in C:\xampp\htdocs\Email\Mail.php on line 20

Warning: fopen(/htdocs/Email/CashPickup.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Email\Mail.php on line 21

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Email\Mail.php on line 22

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\Email\Mail.php on line 23
```

Note: My code run in web server without error and it works properly but after I run it to localhost, those errors shows.

Code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* Email Detials */

$mail_to      = "email";
$from_mail    = "email";
$from_name    = "title";
$reply_to     = "";
$subject      = "subj...";
$message_body = "";

/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */

$file_name = "filename.xml";
$path      = "\htdocs\Email\";

// Read the file content

$file      = $path . $file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle    = fopen($file, "r");
$content   = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */

$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header

$header = "From: " . $from_mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $reply_to . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"";

$message_body .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */

$message_body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message_body .= "\r\n";
$message_body .= "$message_body\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */

$message_body .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message_body .= " name=\"" . $file_name . "\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message_body .= " filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"\r\n";
$message_body .= "\r\n" . $content . "\r\n";
$message_body .= "--" . $boundary . "--\r\n";

// Send email
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message_body, $header)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: remember, your code needs 4 spaces before every line. After posting, always look at your post, and then fix obvious mistakes.

Comment: the syntax highlighter already shows the problem

Comment: @Ghost my code is run properly in my web server but when I try to run to the localhost, the errors shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep I found it, you're using the escaping character, `\`.

Check it out,

```
$path      = "\htdocs\Email\";
```

should be

```
$path      = "\\htdocs\\Email\\";
```

Or better yet, just use `/`:

```
$path      = "/htdocs/Email/";
```

Comment: @user4212650 `/htdocs/Email/CashPickup.xml` doesn't exist. You're probably missing `C:/path/to/htdocs/...`, or simply, if your files are already in the document root, use `Email/CashPickup.xml` as the file name.